# Data Binding with D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

What am I missing, or doing wrong, that I do not see the text (Hello) five times on the page?

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Data Binding</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>D3.js</h1>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="data-script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**data-script.js**

```
var dataset = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

d3.select('body')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('p')
    .text("Hello");
```

Comment: You're missing `.selectAll("p")` after `d3.select("body")` for the outcome you want. `"p"` can be a difference selector e.g. `".testParagraph"` etc.

Comment: Spot on, thank you! Please transfer your comment to an answer, so I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert `<p>` nodes within `<body>` per the length of the `dataset` array you can create an empty selection within the the selection of `<body>` e.g.:

```js
// data-script.js
var dataset = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

d3.select('body')
  .selectAll("p") // <----- this is the extra line you need
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append('p')
  .text("Hello");
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Data Binding</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>D3.js</h1>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="data-script.js"></script> -->
  </body>

</html>
```

The selector `"p"` can be whatever you need e.g. a class `".testParagraph"`.